# How can I condense all these similar views into one?

Tags: html, django, view, django-templates, django-views

All of these views are very similar, and I would like to condense them into one view.

```
class SummerIntents(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'admin/hr/intent_forms/summer_intents.html'

    @user_is_staff
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SummerIntents, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SummerIntents, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # These functions are found in util.py
        update_date = get_update_date()
        active_users = get_active_users(self)

        context['summer_info'] = SummerInfo.objects.filter(employee__in=active_users, date_modified__gte=update_date.date, active=True).order_by('position','employee__last_name')
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SummerIntents, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        file_name = "summer_intent_forms"

        update_date = get_update_date()
        active_users = get_active_users(self)
        info = SummerInfo.objects.filter(employee__in=active_users, date_modified__gte=update_date.date, active=True).order_by('position','employee__last_name')
        student_intents = get_student_intents(active_users, update_date, 'summer', info)

        return intents_to_csv(student_intents, file_name)


class WinterIntents(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'admin/hr/intent_forms/winter_intents.html'

    @user_is_staff
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(WinterIntents, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(WinterIntents, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # These functions are found in util.py
        update_date = get_update_date()
        active_users = get_active_users(self)

        context['winter_info'] = WinterInfo.objects.filter(employee__in=active_users, date_modified__gte=update_date.date, active=True).order_by('position','employee__last_name')
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(WinterIntents, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        file_name = "winter_intent_forms"

        update_date = get_update_date()
        active_users = get_active_users(self)
        info = WinterInfo.objects.filter(employee__in=active_users, date_modified__gte=update_date.date, active=True).order_by('position','employee__last_name')
        student_intents = get_student_intents(active_users, update_date, 'winter', info)

        return intents_to_csv(student_intents, file_name)


class FallIntents(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'admin/hr/intent_forms/fall_intents.html'

    @user_is_staff
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(FallIntents, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FallIntents, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # These functions are found in util.py
        update_date = get_update_date()
        active_users = get_active_users(self)

        context['fall_info'] = FallInfo.objects.filter(employee__in=active_users, date_modified__gte=update_date.date, active=True).order_by('position','employee__last_name')
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(FallIntents, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        file_name = "fall_intent_forms"

        update_date = get_update_date()
        active_users = get_active_users(self)
        info = FallInfo.objects.filter(employee__in=active_users, date_modified__gte=update_date.date, active=True).order_by('position','employee__last_name')
        student_intents = get_student_intents(active_users, update_date, 'fall')

        return intents_to_csv(student_intents, file_name, info)
```

I am open to one main view they all inherit from, but would that mean I have to pass some variables through context? Such as `update_date` and `active_users`? I would prefer not to add another method on top of these ones, especially since they are already so short and a main view to inherit from wouldn't do too much good. Secondly, they each have a post method that saves the templates as CSV file when a button is clicked, and I don't know how to condense that so that all the buttons still function properly. Finally, they all have different templates, would I have to condense them into one file as well? That's what I'm hoping to do eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by having to "pass some variables through context", but inheritance is definitely the way to go here.

Note even within each view you have some duplication, such as getting the Info objects which can be abstracted out into a separate method. Note also that you can avoid defining `dispatch` just to decorate it if instead you add the django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin and define `test_func`.

```
class Intents(UserPassesTestMixin, TemplateView):

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_staff

    def get_template_names(self):
         return 'admin/hr/intent_forms/{}_intents.html'.format(self.season_name)

    def get_info_items(self):
        update_date = get_update_date()
        active_users = get_active_users(self)
        return self.info_model.objects.filter(employee__in=active_users, date_modified__gte=update_date.date, active=True).order_by('position','employee__last_name')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['{}_info'.format(self.season_name)] = self.get_info_items()
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file_name = "{}_intent_forms".format(self.season_name)
        info = self.get_info_items()
        student_intents = get_student_intents(active_users, update_date, self.season_name, info)

        return intents_to_csv(student_intents, file_name)

class SummerIntents(Intents):
    season_name = 'summer'
    info_model = SummerInfo

class WinterIntents(Intents):
    season_name = 'winter'
    info_model = WinterInfo

class FallIntents(Intents):
    season_name = 'fall'
    info_model = FallInfo
```

(Also, it's a bit odd to have `get_active_users` as a utility method that accepts the view class as a parameter. Are you sure that shouldn't be a method on the view?)

Comment: This looks good! How could I get this to work? Because After copying, pasting, and importing UserPassesTestMixin, I'm getting the error that there isn't a template for the SummerIntents view. Do I have to call the ```get_template_names``` function? EDIT: Oh I see you can have the method or the var ```template_names``` defined. It still needs a template though so somethings not happening

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to have the subclasses actually inherit from the Intents class...

Comment: Alright, after some testing and changing a few things it works! Thank you so much! This really helps a lot